# Unable to drop mydashlets on my Dashboard

Tags: dashboard

Can't drop my dashlet in the civicrm dashoard. 
I can drag it out but it wont drop anywhere.

Here is an image of me dragging it but the dashboard isn't opening up to drop it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by pasting the file where it was looking for it. However, it is disconcerting that it is looking for the file in the wrong place.

Comment: Since this was your resolution, please mark it as the accepted answer. It's perfectly acceptable on this site to answer your own question!

Answer (score 0):

Your dashboard configuration page doesn't look right - you can compare it to the demo site to see what I mean: http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard

It seems like you have some CSS (or possibly JavaScript) that's overriding the standard CSS.  You may want to open the developer console and look for `div id="existing-dashlets-col-0"` - see screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked at the console and there is an error : 2http://test-fcbeta2.pantheon.io/sites/all/extensions/css/dashboard.css?r=GlMRy Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)... 

It is looking for my dashboard.css file in the wrong place.
This is strange as it isn't doing this on my other sites which are almost identical to this one. my dashboard.css lived in profiles/civicrm_starterkit/modules/civicrm/css/dashboard.css